# Can't read real password in SQL database user table

Tags: sql, wordpress, encryption, passwords

I'm sure this is a total noob question, but I exported a user table from my SQL database in phpMyAdmin, and the passwords are all encrypted, I need to be able to see the real passwords because they're being imported into a new wordpress website. It's not going to go over well if the people have to enter some long crazy alphanumeric string, LOL!

Can anyone give me a solution to this, bearing in mind I'm no SQL expert?

Comment: How are they "encrypted"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no way to find the original string from a hash, or more simply, there's no way to unencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible to crack. Just most people won't know how to do it or have the processing power to do it if your passwords are strong.
Here's a good article on it if you're interested.
http://alandykes.com/2013/05/09/how-easily-can-i-hack-your-sql-server-password-edition/

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to decrypt the passwords, they are hopefully hashes and could look like this:
`$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa`

When a user logs in, the password can be verified against this hash, and this should work the same way with your new wordpress site.